# Stripped Threads in Hyrdo Boost

Tags: brakes, stripped-thread, hydroboost

[image][image]From the pictures above, I have a hydroboost that I need to attach a hose/line to. The problem is that when trying to screw in the bolt with just my fingers, I get a little bit of resistance, and the bolt pops out. To me, the bolt looked slightly damaged, so I went ahead and got a new line since it seemed like the threads in the hole were fine. I am still have the same issue however. Is there anyway for me to get past this? Is it possible for me to rethread the hole while still keeping the same size? I would like to refrain from getting a new hydroboost unit all together. Thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, those are tapered pipe threads. The male fitting is a little narrower at the tip and broadens to matching female threads for a pressure proof seal along with O-ring. These aluminum fittings require some finesse, aligning the fitting  perfectly when hand threading while pressing the fitting on. If you can,  carefully remove the O-ring and clean debris on both fittings. Put the O-ring back on, lube the fitting and align the fitting perfectly while screwing on the nut into its female mating hole. You may have to use a wrench to continue threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top thread in the hole were stripped. Using a tap for the same hole and thread size cut out any deformed threads that were blocking the threads on the bolt. Can use some teflon tape on the fitting if there is a leak afterwards.